# How to capture the output of echoing something to proc

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I want to execute the command `echo m > /proc/sysrq-trigger` and capture its output.  It prints out memory usage information.  I'm on uClinux on a Blackfin processor.  Whenever I execute this, the output goes out the serial port, even if I execute it from a Telnet connection.  I want to be able to capture its output to a file.

Based on my findings, it appears it is somehow hard-coded to use the RS-232 port rather than stdout.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is printed to a kernel log ring buffer, which is available as `/proc/kmsg` (and taken from there by syslog or similiar process to be printed on console).

You can easily extract data from `/proc/kmsg` by simply reading it:

```
# cat /proc/kmsg
```

Use file redirection to write it into file:

```
# cat /proc/kmsg > /tmp/my-memory-info
```

Comment: Looks like I need to start the `cat /proc/kmsg` with re-direction first, then issue the `echo m`.  Make sense?
Also, another issue is that I get the full printout the first time, but thereafter only the last line or so e.g. `<4>7180 pages non-shared` or `es non-shared`.

Comment: On the capture from `/proc/kmsg`, each line has a <6> or <4> preceding it, presumably a logging level because it is coming out of the log buffer.  This doesn't show up on RS-232.  Any way to avoid that?

Comment: @Jon: as alternative to my simpler approach, you may try to configure your `syslog`. Check `/etc/rsyslog.conf` for example (but this works only for rsyslog).

Comment: modifying syslog is not really feasible in my situation, but I think I have a workable solution.  Thanks for your help!